# app.use(path, router) matches but how do I extract named parameters in path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to separate routes into individual files with the app.use('/', router) pattern employed by default in an express initialized application. For example:

```
var users = require('./routes/users');
// ...
app.use('/users', users);
```

I've added a posts router for a blog, which works fine:

```
var posts = require('./routes/posts');
// ...
app.use('/posts', posts);
```

However, I'm now adding comments subroutes on posts. I need to employ a named parameter in the path supplied to `app.use` so that I can identify the post in addition to the comment:

```
var comments = require('./routes/comments');
// ...
app.use('/posts/:pid/comments', comments);
```

The routes/comments.js file looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('all comments + ', req.params.pid);
});

// ...
```

A path such as `/posts/1/comments/34` correctly matches and the callback in router/comments.js is executed, but req.params.pid is undefined.

Is it possible to employ the app.use(path, router) pattern with named parameters in the path? If so how do I get at that :pid named parameter?

Answer (score 1):

How about this

**comments.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:pid/comments', function(req,res){
    res.send('all comments for post id: ' + req.params.pid);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**posts.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.send('show all posts');
});

router.get('/:pid', function(req,res){
    res.send('show post with id: ' + req.params.pid);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**finally app.js**

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var comments = require('./routes/comments');
var posts = require('./routes/posts');

app.use('/posts', comments);
app.use('/posts', posts);
```

**Points to note:**

- In comments.js, I use **'/:pid/comments'** as the path to match, so that the post id is available there.
- In app.js, I pass the **comments routes first** to the app and the **posts routes after that**, so that the comment routes are matched first
- Both comments and posts have the **root path '/posts'**

Sorry for the brevity. I just find this self-explanatory. If anything is confusing, please ask in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the router to use `comments` for `/posts/:pid/comments/`, you're effectively throwing away the `:pid` parameter, because that parameter isn't available in the routing function defined in `comments.js`. Instead, you should define this route inside `posts.js`:

```
router.get("/:pid/comments", function(req, res) {
    res.send("all comments " + req.params.pid);
});
```

Naturally, one would expect more complex logic to be required, which should be defined in a separate file and required in `posts.js`:

```
var comments = require("comments");

router.use("/:pid/comments", function(req, res) {
    comments.renderGet(req.params.what, req, res);
});
```

Define your logic in `comments.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    renderGet: function(id, req, res) {
                   res.send("all comments " + id);
               },

     // ... other routes, logic, etc.
};
```

Comment: That's what I've fallen back on for now. This strikes me as a bug or at the minimum a reasonable feature request, in addition to it preventing parallel code constructions in routes/posts.js and routes/comments.js. I'll wait a bit longer to see if anyone else has another suggestion and then mark this answer correct if not. Thanks.

Comment: I agree. It seems like a more elegant solution is out there.

Comment: Apparently this is coming! The feature is available in Express 4.5.0 or higher is works as follows: `var router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });`